Is there a configuration that allows rotated files to be deleted after a period of time?
According to the documentation for max_days here, if the timestamp in a file is older than the max_days, the file gets deleted.
On the other hand, the documentation here states that if the file is older than max_days, the file gets rotated. This is what I'm observing in my case. The files are not deleted after the max_days period, and unrotated files get rotated once they're max_days old.
Is there a way to delete rotated files after a set period of time?

I am not familiar with the application you are trying to configure, but if you are on Linux, then I suggest you type man find and look at the -mtime +days and -exec command {} \; options. With the -mtime option, you can find files that have not been modified for (at least) the specified number of days, and the -exec option will execute a shell command for the specified file. In your case, I suggest you start with -exec ls -l {} \; to verify that find is locating suitably old files, and then migrate to using -exec rm -f {} \; to delete those old files.
You can put the find command into a shell script and arrange for that to be executed, say, once per day. man cron might help you with that.
